# meteor mongo remove callback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

> Not working Document remove callback always error = null Query return
>   is wrong, null . query return is cor null

```
activity.remove: (id) => {
        try {
            activitys.remove({
                $and: [{
                        _id: id
                    },
                    {
                        owner: Meteor.userId()
                    }
                ]
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                if (!error) {
                   console.log("success");
                } else {
                   console.log("error oldu");
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(e.error, e.reason);
        } 
}
```

Comment: There's no need to include the other query for `owner: Meteor.userId()` when you already have the `_id` in the query

Comment: @chridam I think he wants to provoke an error using this query but does not get one as expected. 

Codegr can you please describe in more detail what you intend to get out of this?